# Name of spring actuated component

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image: Spring on shaft with retaining clip]

I need to get another component like this but I can't seem to find any manufacturers / retailers.

To describe it:
It is spring mounted on a shaft and retained by bushing on the top and an enlarged shaft diameter bottom. E-clip on top is for securing shaft in place. Spring pushes the pin down.

If anyone knows what they are called, I would like to know.

Comment: A spring-loaded pin maybe?

Comment: They are almost what I need but they seem to be connection pins (like test probes). I would need something like that but made out of steel preferably.

Comment: Generically, this would be called a spring plunger. They are common with wither male threads on the exterior, or for press-fitting. I'm not sure what you'd call one that mounts that way specifically.

Comment: What is this part used for?  Is it used for workholding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a press-fit spring plunger?
[image]

Some product codes to get you started:
 - MCS: 05137617, 05137815, 65155566
 - Grainger: 2YLK5, 2YLN2, 2YLL9